# Freely move images inside a div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

How can I add a feature inside a div `contenteditable` to allow free movement of images? I want to be able to click and drag the images to place it wherever I want inside the `contenteditable`. I want a vanilla JavaScript solution for this( without jquery) if possible.

```css
            #myContent {
                height: 90vh;
                width: 62vw;
                background-color: #dfdfdf;
                padding-left: 2%;
                padding-right: 2%;
                padding-top: 5px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
            #myContent:focus {
                outline: none;
            }
                #myContent::-webkit-scrollbar {
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div contenteditable="true" id="myContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with contenteditible, per se. You just need to declared the element as [draggable and then work with the draggable API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable).

Comment: If you have an image inside your contenteditable div content, you can simply drag it into the new position. No additional work needed.

Comment: @MrCoconut It doesn't seem to allow me to move it

Comment: Can you provide some code to reproduce it?

Comment: @Scott Marcus  How can I keep checking for pasted images? My program will just check it in the beginning, and then it won't allow to move the rest of the images

Comment: Your posted question doesn't say anything about pasting images either. For that, you'd set up an event handler for that event. Please focus on a single question, post the code that you are working with and what you've tried.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Since I'm making a contenteditable, I obviously want my images to be dynamic, so I want to allow users to paste images, and allow those to be moveable

Comment: That could be, but questions should be focused on a single thing and the question should be clear about what it is asking about. Nothing is "obvious" about your situation, which is why you must clearly specify it in your question.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Sorry I wasn't clear, but I'm in a lose-lose situation. If I add that I want to allow pasting images, then my question isn't focused on 1 particular question and if I don't add it then I'm not clear about my question. So I'm expecting an answer that answers my question taking into account the pasting of images.